# Is AgensGraph possible to support HA?

Tags: graph-databases, agens-graph

I have used PostgreSQL and ever heard that AgensGraph is based on PostgreSQL and Graph Database, so it is very robust, fully-featured and ready to enterprise use.
So, I wonder how AgensGraph supports High Availability (HA).

Answer (score 0):

AgensGraph supports HA. You can configure AgensGraph clusters using stream-based replication. Currently, it supports only Active-Standby clusters. And you can use external tools like pg-pool to configure high-availability setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cluster solution for AgensGraph HA, that is called Pgpool.
You know, AgensGraph is operated by stream-based replication for sharing data in Active-Standby operating system.

Pgpool can supply AgensGraph with load balancing and failover clustering for high-availability.

below link page for more information.

[enter link description here](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/tutorial-arch.html)